# Javascript function not defined?

Tags: javascript

I've defined a javascript function:

```
<script>
function expand()
{
  parent.getElementById("elementA").style.height = 300px;
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to call it onClick:

```
<div id="elementB" onclick="expand()">Notif</div>
```

The web console tells me that expand is not defined when I click on it.

Comment: Can you post the complete code you're using?

Comment: when you call it add `this` to your function call in the dom.  `expand(this)`. this will pass a reference to the dom element that the event is attached to.  just an fyi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your javascript, it should be `'300px'` (a string); This is why the script does not load (which web console probably also tells you), so the function is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting quotes around 300px, i.e.

```
<script>
function expand()
{
    parent.getElementById("elementA").style.height = '300px';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning the value for height, you must assign it as a string value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function expand()
{
  // Need to assign the value as a string
  parent.getElementById("elementA").style.height = '300px'; 
}
</script>
```

I'm assuming this is within an iframe given the parent reference. If not, you might want to change **parent** to **document**.